# How to fix - Executor is required to handle java.util.concurrent.Callable return values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a controller in Spring Boot/Spring Data Rest where my handler downloads a file like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/orderAttachments/{id}/download")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadAttachment(@PathVariable("id") Long attachmentID, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = fileManager.getInputStream(orderAttachment);

        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {

            int numberOfBytesToWrite;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
            }

            inputStream.close();
        };

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentLength(orderAttachment.getFileSize())
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""  + orderAttachment.getFileName()+ "\"")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(responseBody);
    }
```

I got this error in the console

```
!!!
An Executor is required to handle java.util.concurrent.Callable return values.
Please, configure a TaskExecutor in the MVC config under "async support".
The SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor currently in use is not suitable under load.
-------------------------------
Request URI: '/api/v1/orderAttachments/163/download'
!!!
```

But everything works, I can download the file from calling the API

Comment: Can you add your project source to run to check what is really happening ?

Answer (score 14):

For starters it is a warning and not an error. If it was an error your application wouldn't start or work. It is a warning telling you that the default used `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` shouldn't be used in production.

The `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` creates a new `Thread` when something needs to be processed asynchronously. Each thread takes up 1MB of memory by default (and some processing power). Now imagine someone issuing 100000 calls to this API. This would also mean 100000 threads (times the memory and each a little cpu power). It would cripple your application and maybe even kill it.

**NOTE:** If you are on Spring Boot 2.1.x or higher a default `TaskExecutor` will be configured and used for you. **However** if you have something in your configuration that disables the auto-configuration (like an `@EnableWebMvc` on an `@Configuration` class for instance). To configure that executor (with threads etc) check the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling).

You can also manually create a `TaskExecutor` and associate that with Spring MVC.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor mvcTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10); 
    return taskExecutor;
  }

  public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setTaskExecutor(mvcTaskExecutor());
  }

}
```

Now this dedicated `TaskExecutor` will be used for the async handling in Spring MVC. However as mentioned this should already be pre-configured by Spring Boot if you haven't disabled auto-configuration (maybe even by accident!).

Answer (score 3):

It is just a warning (that is why you still are able to download requested file) and Spring's suggestion to define your own `TaskExecutor` rather than using the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which, as the message states, is not suitable under load.

`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` fires up a new Thread for each task and does not reuse them. If you haven't configured limit on concurrent threads, it is by default unlimited.

```
@Configuration
class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Bean
    protected WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.setTaskExecutor([your task executor]);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Use the above configuration to define your own `TaskExecutor` that suits your needs and get rid of the warning.

Comment: I added that code, didnt do anything. Same warning.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following did the trick:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("mvc-task-executor-");
        executor.initialize();
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(executor);
    }

}
```

By this means a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is specified for the MVC context.

Make sure your application picks up the `@Configuration` class! If your main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, this should happen automatically.

Also, make sure to configure your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` appropriately to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot in 2.1.0 provides auto configuration for task executors and uses for `@EnableAsync` and Spring MVC Async support.

There is no task executor bean / webMvcConfigurer configuration is needed from application. If you have one please remove it and you should be good.

If you like to control the values you can adjust using applicaion properties/yml file with `spring.task.execution.*`. Full listing can be found [`here`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

More details [`here`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20751) and [`here`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1563)

Comment: I never added any configuration of my own. Yet it still gives this error. You answer doesn't tell me how to get rid of this error. I'm using spring boot 2.1.9

Comment: You should not be seeing this error if you use 2.1.0 and higher without any extra configuration in the first place. Could you share what all configuration you have right now ?

Comment: fyi - I've verified with 2.1.9 and it is working as I explained in the answer.

Comment: I added `@EnableAsync` to my project and SpringBoot created a `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` automatically; perfect.